# Angular 15 : Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 15. Created a new Angular component as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent {

}
```

When I implement the `OnInit` interface,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

I get following error.

> Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an
> explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)

Detailed Configuration of my project.

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "client1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you generate the component?

Comment: @syahiruddin using the Angular-CLI command `ng g c foo`.

Comment: Everything you shared looks normal, and I tried to reproduce it on my end looks fine. Either you re-run or try to generate again.

Comment: @syahiruddin tried everything re-installed node js, angular, and typescript. nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48741.

After disabling the VS code extension "Angular Language Service" everything works fine now.

If you are facing the same error even before building or running the application, try disabling VS code extensions related to Angular or JavaScript. Might work.

Comment: Saved me so much headache. Thank you.